# How to use table variable in dynamic sql in SAP HANA?

Tags: sql, hana

Inside a procedure, I use a table variable to store the some result from table A .

I have to use this table variable in dynamic sql .

Eg)

```
Call Procedure A()

Begin

VAR_TAB = select customer_id from table_A;

EXEC ' select * from'||: var_tab;

End;
```

The above code will throw error. Anyone has a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case:

You can use the table variable like a temporary table and can use it w/o dynamic sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE c AS 
BEGIN
    var_tab = SELECT customer_id FROM table_A ;
    select * from :var_tab;
END;
```

If the result contains the actual table name, you have to use dynamic SQL and can access the *table variable* value as *array*:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE b AS 
BEGIN
    var_tab = SELECT customer_id FROM table_A ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' select * from '||:var_tab.customer_id[1];
END;
```

or use a *scalar variable*:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE a AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_tab nvarchar(20);
    SELECT customer_id INTO var_tab FROM table_A ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' select * from '||var_tab;
END;
```

Comment: To me it appeared as if the OP wanted to use the table variable as a table/view/subquery in the dynamic SQL. Extracting a single value from the table variable is not achieving that.

Comment: added 1st variant in answer to address comment from Lars